# MySQL - Get Column Names & SELECT At Same Time?

Tags: mysql, nim-lang

I know of the following two ways to show column names of a table:

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename`

and

`DESCRIBE tablename`

How can I do a `SELECT FROM tablename` and also return the columns (If possible)?

The reason I want to do this is because in Nim, the [MySQL module](https://nim-lang.org/docs/db_mysql.html) doesn't provide any proc for returning an associative array of results that you can reference by column name. You have to get results like x[0]. I'd like to create my own module for this and I don't want to execute two different queries for it.

Comment: Your `SELECT` statement should state the columns it wants to return: `SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... FROM tablename`.

Comment: @Barmar: Not if you use `*`.

Comment: I can't answer this question because I don't know how to make a Nim module, but the MySQL C API gives you field names as well as row data, so you _should_ have access to this information by default. (Consequently, I'm surprised to hear that Nim's default API doesn't expose this information.)

Comment: There's no way to do this in SQL. You could create a stored procedure that does it, by using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to construct dynamic SQL for a query that returns both informations.

Comment: But that still means two queries have to be executed: one to get the information schema, and then the query that it constructs.

Comment: Okay I didn't realise the C API performs two queries under the hood each time.

Comment: Guess I'll accept all the infos of these comments in the form of a cohesive answer if anyone wants to do it.